# Read text from dynamic link and process before displaying

Tags: javascript, download

I need to write a very simple page to test the functionality of another program. It doesn't have to be fail-safe as the tester will know how to use it.

I need to call a page that gets a parameter (a key) in GET or POST query string. Using that key the embedded javascript should GET a fixed URL appended with the key. It gets back a string that's a few hundred bytes max. It has to base64 decode it (have the code for that already) and display it some way. So the main steps are:

1) Get 'key' from query string.

2) Do a GET to predefURL+key.

3) Put the answer into a variable. (The full body.)

4) Decode it.

5) Display.

I need a solution for 2 and 3. I'd like to stick to pure javascript as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onGetResponse() 
 {
  if (xhReq.readyState != 4)  { return; }
  var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
  // Process/decode/display your response here
 }

 var xhReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "predefURL?key=myKey", true);
 xhReq.onreadystatechange = onGetResponse;
 xhReq.send(null);
```

http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call

Comment: I formated your code and corrected the error on calling onGetResponse. Other than that it does work. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I copied and pasted and forgot to modify that one! I'm on a mobile and it's hard to use SO haha

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering even from a mobile :)